# UIButton background image looks fine in sim, but not on device

Tags: iphone, uibutton, background-image

I manually set my UIButton's background by using the following:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

On the simulator this looks fine, however on the device it looks horrendous.  It looks like this:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this.  I do have an autoresizing mask set (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`), but disabling it still causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Somebody else on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785986/resizing-an-image-with-stretchableimagewithleftcapwidth) was getting stretch artifacts because of a "Compress PNG" files" project setting.  How is your's set?